# add class to div if error return angular js

Tags: angularjs

code is working fine, and get data through API(http.get), 
if there is a wrong entry, its return 401 error, 
how to add class "error" to div,

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="vm.frmmn()">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="?">
    <label>Tile</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-1" placeholder="001">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="02">
    <span class="help-block" ng-if="error">Error : {{error}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      Search Mobile Network
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
 function frmmn() {

   var path_mn = api + "operator/" + vm.mcc + "/" + vm.mnc;
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: path_mn,
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer.token
     }
   }).then(function(resp) {
     $scope.itemsm = resp.data;
   }).catch(function(err) {
     if (err.status === 404) {
       $scope.error = "error : " + err.status
     };
   });
 }
```

Comment: `<div ng-class="{ error: error }">`

Comment: <div ng-class="{'has-error': errorcode == 401 }"> here errorcode is error code coming from server. save this to scope variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-class` build in directive [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) is a good example on how to use `ng-class`

**Example**

```
    function frmmn(){
        var path_mn = api + "operator/" + vm.mcc + "/" + vm.mnc;
        $scope.status = {
            error_404 : false; //define a boolean variable
        }
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url: path_mn,
            headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer '+bearer.token}
            }).then(function(resp){
                $scope.itemsm=resp.data;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                if(err.status === 404){
                    $scope.error = "error : " + err.status 
                    $scope.status.error_404 = true; // set errorStatus to true
                };
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="help-block" ng-class="{'error':status.error_404 }" here ng-if="error" >Error : {{error}}</span>
```

**CSS**

```
 .error{
       color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<div ng-class="{ 
       'error': error condition here
}"></div>
```

'error' is class and put the condition next to it.

Answer (score 2):

On addition to the answer above, reset the `$scope.error`on `$http`start to hide the error message on 'retry'. Use `$scope.error = undefined`.

Changes on the `frmmn` function :

```
function frmmn(){
    var path_mn = api + "operator/" + vm.mcc + "/" + vm.mnc;
    $scope.error = undefined;
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url: path_mn,
        headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer '+bearer.token}
        }).then(function(resp){
            $scope.itemsm=resp.data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            if(err.status === 404){
                $scope.error = "error : " + err.status 
            };
    });
}
```